# accessing other socket inside the socket.on('connection') in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm new with node.js and socket.io.

How to access other socket inside socket.on('connection') ?
Here is my server side code:

server side *index.js*:

```
io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {

    socket.on("tree", function(fruit){
        var fruit = "strawberry";
        console.log(fruit); // result: strawberry
    });

    socket.on("drink", function(juice){
        //How to access var fruit here? (strawberry)
    });

};
```

Thank you for any help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want some data (such as the avatar) to be available for future events after it is received, then you have to save that data somewhere in your server and save it in a way that you know which piece of data goes with which connection.

There are a zillion ways to structure that from saving it to a property on the socket, to saving it a map of username --> userdata to saving it in a database.  The general idea is that you save it somewhere when you receive it so that however you want to retrieve the data in the future for use in some future events, you can find it in that data structure or database.

From your code example:

```
io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {

    var savedFruit;
    socket.on("tree", function(fruit){
        savedFruit = fruit;
        console.log(fruit); // result: strawberry
    });

    socket.on("drink", function(juice){
        // You can access the savedFruit variable here which will only have a
        // value if the "tree" message has already been received.
    });

});
```

Comment: Hi jfriend00,

Yes, I already use database for this. It's just example code.
The main question is still on "how to access other socket inside socket.on('connection') in socket.io"

cheers...

Comment: @Kiky - what do you mean other socket?  What other socket?  Your sample code is asking how to access the avatar, not how to access another socket.

Comment: jfriend00, Ok.. it's not about avatar. I update my question. Hope you understand now. Sorry.. because I'm really new with javascript and socket.io. Thank you..

Comment: @Kiky - the answer is still the same for the `fruit`.  You save that value in some place that is accessible to your other event handler.  In your particular case, you could just rename the `fruit` variable to not conflict with your function argument and move the declaration up one scope level above where it is declared now so that it is available to both event handlers.

Comment: jfriend00...  umm.. can you answer with your sample code?
Thank you for guiding me...

Comment: @Kiky - OK one example added to my answer.

Comment: jfriend00 reallyy Thank you for your help. I'm understand now. well.. this should be a basic rite? It's so helped me much to learn... :D